# Using seq.Date as breaks in stat_bin for time-series

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to bin time-series data from several years of observation by month using the `stat_bin` function in `ggplot2`.  The code looks like this:

```
month.breaks<-seq.Date(from=min(afg$DateOccurred),to=max(afg$DateOccurred),by="month")  # All months, for breaks
report.region<-ggplot(afg,aes(x=DateOccurred))+stat_bin(aes(y=..density..,fill=Type),breaks=month.breaks)+facet_wrap(~Region)
print(report.region)
```

When I run print, however, I get the following error:

```
Error in `+.Date`(left, right) : binary + is not defined for Date objects
```

If I am reading this correctly, the plus operator is not defined for `Date` objects and thus it is not possible to perform this type of binning?

Comment: Quick idea: coerce the breaks to numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your error as follows:

```
> break.dates <- seq.Date(from=as.Date('2001-01-01'),
                          to=as.Date('2001-04-01'),
                          by="month") 
> break.dates
[1] "2001-01-01" "2001-02-01" "2001-03-01" "2001-04-01"
## add an offset, which increases the dates by a day
> break.dates + 1
[1] "2001-01-02" "2001-02-02" "2001-03-02" "2001-04-02"
## try to add two date objects together - this does not make sense!
> break.dates + break.dates
Error in `+.Date`(break.dates, break.dates) :
  binary + is not defined for Date objects
```

It does not make sense to add two dates together, since there is no natural "zero" on the date scale. However the `+` operator is defined for `Date` objects in situations where it makes sense.

Comment: I believe ggplot2 is throwing the error, as I am using dates as the x-axis scale.

Answer (score 3):

When I've gotten that error from ggplot2 in other circumstances, I've been able to get away with using as.numeric() around the sequence I'm using for breaks. For example,

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

somedates <- ymd(20130101) + ddays(runif(100, 0, 364)) #generate some fake event dates
somedatesformatted <- data.frame(Dates=as.Date(somedates)) #format them as data ggplot likes
monthbins <- as.numeric(seq(as.Date('2013-01-01'), as.Date('2014-01-01'), '1 month')) # generate breaks for binning event dates and wrap in as.numeric()

ggplot(somedatesformatted, aes(x=Dates)) + 
    stat_bin(breaks=monthbins) +
    ylab("Events per Month") +
    ylim(c(0,30)) +
    scale_x_date(breaks = '1 month',
             labels = date_format("%b"),
             limits = c(as.Date('2013-01-01'), as.Date('2013-12-31')))
```

Comment: This is great but so others can use it without a hickup  

1- use library(scales), otherwise date_format("%b") won't work

2- weekbins should be called monthbins perhaps?  

3- the end of the break should be as.Date('2014-01-01') so you have the break for the month of december:

monthbins <- as.numeric(seq(as.Date('2013-01-01'), as.Date('2014-01-01'), '1 month'))

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you can get the same result if you just transform the data first, *then* pass it to the plot method.

For instance (time series data in months binned by year):

```
data(AirPassengers)   # time series in months (supplied w/ default R install)
AP = AirPassengers
library(xts)
X = as.xts(AP)      # need xts object to pass to xts binning method
ndx = endpoints(X, on="years")    # binning method requires indices for desired bin freq
X_yr = period.apply(x=X, INDEX=ndx, FUN=sum)   # X_yr is the binned data
```

Comment: I am not sure this solution were work for me; first because the data has a single column with date; and second, I do not think xts objects are compatible with ggplot2.